# Find Queue Size of the Link in Ns2

Tags: queue, size, ns2

Simulation Code

```
 set ns [new Simulator]
 set nf [open out.nam w]
 $ns namtrace-all $nf

 proc finish {} {
global ns nf
$ns flush-trace
close $nf
exec nam out.nam &
exit 0
 }

set n0 [$ns node]
set n1 [$ns node]

$ns duplex-link $n0 $n1 1Mb 10ms DropTail


set udp0 [new Agent/UDP]
$ns attach-agent $n0 $udp0

set cbr0 [new Application/Traffic/CBR]
$cbr0 set packetSize_ 500
$cbr0 set interval_ 0.0005
$cbr0 attach-agent $udp0


set null0 [new Agent/Null] 
$ns attach-agent $n1 $null0

$ns connect $udp0 $null0


$ns at 0.5 "$cbr0 start"
$ns at 4.5 "$cbr0 stop"


$ns at 5.0 "finish"
$ns run
```

This Code generates two nodes n0 ,n1 and link between them.
I want to find the current queue Size of the link between n0 and n1.
can any one help??

Answer (score 1):

When not specified, a simulation parameter is determined in the ns-default.tcl file (located in /tcl/lib/). For the queue size, it s value is by default, set to 50 packets:

```
Queue set limit_ 50
```

If you have several links, and you want all of them to have the same queue size, you may add in your .tcl file the following:

```
Queue set limit_ $queuesize
```

If you have several links, but you want each of them to have a given queue size, you may:

```
$ns duplex-link $n0 $n1 1Mb 10ms DropTail
$ns queue-limit $n0 $n1 $queuesize1

$ns duplex-link $n2 $n3 1Mb 10ms DropTail
$ns queue-limit $n2 $n3 $queuesize2
```

Hope this helps

Nicolas